# Prove or disprove conditional independence

Tags: probability, independence

Is the following statement true ?

**"If two events E and F are independent, then they are conditionally independent given G ".**

I just learned about conditional independence and need to prove or disprove it. Can someone tell me if the above statement is correct. Also can you prove or disprove it formally ?

Comment: It's false.  Suppose you are tossing a fair die.  Let $E$ be the event "the die comes up even".  Let $F$ be the event "the die comes up $>2$".  Then let $G$ be the event "the die comes up $>1$".

Answer (score 1):

When you conditional on something, actually you are having another probability measure, and independence is a property that depends on which probability measure you are referring to, so in general the statement is incorrect.

A simple example: Consider a coin-flipping experiment, where there are two independent coin flips. Let $E, F$ be the event that head appear in the first and second flip respectively, and $G$ be the event that the total number heads equals to one.